# Using vertex colors and textures in Qt5

Tags: qt, glsl, qt5

I am making a 2D interface in Qt5 and QML (Qt Quick 2.0) and I need to draw a guage (e.g. fuel or the like) that has different colors along it.  For instance, it may be green for most of the arc, then become yellow, and finally red.

I have accomplished this by implementing a custom class derived from QQuickItem which creates a QSGGeometryNode and specifies geometry with vertex colors.  The problem is that the edges are rough (aliased).  FSAA seems overkill, so I want to texture my arc with a gradient that fades out at the edges to get a smooth look.

In order to get a custom material, I started with the simplematerial example:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/scenegraph-simplematerial-simplematerial-cpp.html
This has texture coordinates, but no actual texturing (brilliant!).  None of the "helper" material classes seem to support both vertex colors and texturing.  QSGMaterial doc says nothing about texturing.  How can I texture my vertex colored geometry?